# Typescript add optional property based on another property type

Tags: typescript, types

I have an interface with action property, based on the action type i would like to have optional property added to the interface. Below is the current interface,

```
const FIGHT = `fight`;
const SWIM = `swim`;
const DANCE = `dance`;

type ActionType =
  | typeof FIGHT
  | typeof SWIM
  | typeof DANCE


interface Creator {
  actionType: ActionType;
  typeId: string;
}
```

if the actionType receives value of type SWIM then we would want to add a additional property to the Creator interface, like

```
interface Creator {
  actionType: ActionType;
  typeId: string;
  trained?: string;
}
```

My attempt, `Creator`.

```
interface CreatorBase {
  actionType: ActionType;
  typeId: string;
}

interface CreatorSwim extends CreatorBase {
  actionType: typeof SWIM;
  trained?: string;
}

export type Creator = 
| CreatorBase
| CreatoeSwim
```

I get error TS2339: Property 'trained' does not exist on type 'Creator' if i make an attempt to access `swim` property of an object of type Creator.

Comment: Hm, this is working fine for me. Do you have a typo? I notice "CreatoeSwim" at the end.    interface A  {
        a: string;
    }

    interface B extends A  {
        b: string;
    }

    type C = A|B;

    const c:C = {a: 'a', b: 'b'} 
    c.b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
type ActionType =
  | 'fight'
  | 'swim'
  | 'dane'

interface Trained {
  playerNumber: number,
  type: string
}

interface CreatorBase {
  typeId: string;
  actionType:  ActionType
}

interface UntrainedCreator extends CreatorBase
{
  trained?: never;
}


interface CreatorSwim  extends CreatorBase {
  actionType: 'swim'
  trained?: Trained;
}

export type Creator = 
| UntrainedCreator
| CreatorSwim
```

Answer (score 3):

This does the trick:

```
type ActionType =
  | 'fight'
  | 'swim'
  | 'dane'

interface CreatorBase<TActions> {
  typeId: string;
  actionType:  TActions
}

interface UntrainedCreator extends CreatorBase<Omit<ActionType, 'swim'>>
{
}


interface CreatorSwim  extends CreatorBase<'swim'> {
  trained?: string;
}

export type Creator = 
| UntrainedCreator
| CreatorSwim

const swim: Creator = {actionType: 'swim', typeId : 'i', trained: 'yes'};
const  dane : Creator = {actionType: 'dane', typeId : 'i', };
const  daneError : Creator = {actionType: 'dane', typeId : 'i', trained: ''}; // error
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=27&ssc=89&pln=1&pc=1#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggYxASwPYDsAqlYF5gwwA+MA5AGbIDmAFiKQcWQM4DuyAtg4SaQCYBDdFAbBk6EFABO5AQlgBhKVAEhUUgEIDmUADyZEKDMwB8MAN6Nw0AJJ8AXDGYgp4qgG5Gco1hyOYBkho6MzAAL7AYhLSsvIwAKoSUgLiUHxKKmpSMFAAHpLofMwwGarqWjq6APIcyCC6hsHY0AA0LOxcJibAlhGR4pIycorKZVIAyh2EeQVFJaNZFXqkbJykZpaELinCfAD8js6u6B7hkXkQ6iAw1iOZ6jC4MMAkidup6QvqL-P3Ex2RBDGa6rDiOUpZR4WbxNPztNZtW52GCOUjIUiI5IfVFgKDMUhhTxAkLXGCCYQo35jKHmGEYZpQVHkkSInDI1HotqE4DE5yEZkAUSkUge4K+2SetKC9Lh-CELJubL4lLRGJgmJ2aVRBPcMAA9HqcsLvkA)

Comment: thank you, i did slight modification based on your suggestion and it works for my need without adding generic

Answer (score 0):

So in this case I would imagine Conditional Types are your rescue. You can check if type of your action is actually "swim" if it is so than you map over the keys you want to add.

Look at the following code snippet:

```
type ActionType = "swim" | "run" | "walk"

type Creator <T extends ActionType> = {
    actionType: T
    type: string
} & {[k in T extends "swim" ? 'trained' : never]?: any}

const x: Creator<"swim"> = {
actionType: "run",
type: "swim",
trained: true
}
```